# Android studio - Rider.getName()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was following this tutorial on YouTube and i was doing the same, maybe i have misplaced or forgot a code somewhere which i can't yet recognize, i'm still new to this,

So the error i'm getting is.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.www.riderapp.model.Rider.getName()' on a null object reference
 at com.example.www.riderapp.Home$5$1.onDataChange(Home.java:391)
```

This is my Home.java file method

```
 private void loadAllAvailableDrivers() {
    //Load all drivers within 3km distance

    DatabaseReference driverLocation = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.driver_tbl);
    GeoFire gf = new GeoFire(driverLocation);

    GeoQuery geoQuery = gf.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude()),distance);
    geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, final GeoLocation location) {
            // Use key to get email from table users
            //Table Users is table when driver register account and update information

            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.user_driver_tbl)
                    .child(key)
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            //Because Rider and User model is same properties
                            Rider rider = dataSnapshot.getValue(Rider.class);

                            //Add drivers to map

                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude))
                            .flat(true)
           ERRR ----->      .title(rider.getName())
                            .snippet("Phone : "+rider.getPhone())
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car)));


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });



        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                if(distance <= LIMIT) // distance just find for 3km
                {
                    distance++;
                    loadAllAvailableDrivers();
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}
```

And here is my Rider java class

```
public class Rider {

private String name,email,phone,password;

public Rider(){

}

public Rider(String name, String email, String phone, String password) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

I couldn't find why this is really happening, i think it should be a small thing ;)

Comment: What are your firebase data? Isn't it null? Can you paste at least a screenshot of the firebase json?

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท From where i can see the firebase json?

Comment: Firebase console maybe? You can also check if the output is null or not in `onDataChange()` method.. It (The question error) also does not affect Android Studio. Anyways

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท please check, if these helps http://prntscr.com/kvhb8m , http://prntscr.com/kvhbck

Comment: Are you getting the other data within the current model (rider) ? I couldn’t see Rider array in firebase output.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท i commented the name and tried, i'm not getting the order data either.. any suggestions on what i can try?

Comment: Like I thought. Convert the json output to POJO by this website; http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท i didn't get what you meant there. i'm sorry i'm very new to this, i was following a video after all this time

Comment: I just pasted an answer. It seems like the issue is you model. Also, don't forget to check if it's getting success result in `onDataChange` method or not. However, you could simply use: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DriversInformation").child(key)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i thought, the issue is your ***Rider model class*** which I couldn't see such related array or data in the Firebase json output. But i saw : `DriversInformation`

First, go to Firebase console from which your data(s) are available and copy-paste the output json to this website:

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Check source as `json` and make the output to `GSON` then after downloading the class, drag it to your project.

After that, you'll be able to get access to it like this:

```
ResultPojo result = dataSnapshot.getValue(ResultPojo.class);
```

Then, it will be fine to use or to get the data from the converted `json` to `Gson`. However, it could be done by looping through `dataSnapshot`:

```
ArrayList<String> names= new ArrayList<>();
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

             // blop blop ... do some magic with ds
   }
```